# Algebra problem from an international competition that got me stumped

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

**Problem:** A layer of dough is spread in two identical rectangular molds, then dried. A machine lowers vertically
to cut the contents of the molds into square caramels. In
the second mold is children's caramels,
smaller than those of the first mold. Besides, there are 2006
more caramels in the second mold.
How many caramels are there altogether (total of the two kinds)?

**What I tried:**
I tried to make it a number theory problem by setting $a$, $b$ the number of squares in the base and height of the first mold, and $a \cdot \dfrac{m}{n}$ and  $b \cdot \dfrac{m}{n}$ the number of squares for the second mold, where $a,b,m,n$ are all integers. With the given information it led, after manipulating, to the equation $2006n^2=ab(m-n)(m+n)$. This might be useful but I'm starting to doubt my approach and there's no official solution for this problem (only the answer, which I don't want to look up yet). Hopefully, someone can share their approach to guide me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that we have $a\times b$ caramels in the first mold and $(a+c)\times(b+d)$ in the second. We know that their shape is square so $\frac{a+c}a=\frac{b+d}b$, and $bc=ad$.

We also know that $ab+2006=(a+c)(b+d)$, which means that $2006=(2b+d)c=(2a+c)d$. So $c$ and $d$ must divide $2006$. The prime factors of $2006$ are $\{2,17,59\}$.

We can try for example $c=2$ and $d=17$, this gives $a=58$ and $b=493$. So the total amount of caramels is $2ab+2006=59194$.

Comment: There are more solutions, for example $(16)(472)+2006=(16+2)(472+59)$

Comment: Thanks! It is easy to find all the solutions with the 2 equations you presented (and it helps noticing that $c$ and $d$ must have different parity because 2006 isn't divisible by 4)